# How to avoid websocket reconnection

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am currently building a WebSocket-based instant chat web application, it has more than one page. Every time users refresh or click a link to another page, WebSocket has to be reconnected. Is there a solution to avoid this?

Comment: Really better off using a web-app style front end if you can where the pages are dynamically made on the fly and flipped into view. That way you won't run into this kind of problem. It is relatively simple to do, if you know how to hide and show div's into view, you are half way their!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you refresh the page it will need to reconnect, i dont think there is a way around it.

I would recommend not using page-load to navigate between pages, but to build a single page application.
If you cannot do that in any way, maybe you can have your application in a frame, and the outer html will have the socket. that could work.

Comment: putting into a frame is the only solution I heard so far, and server sent event has the same problem too. It seems to me that I should redesign my front end.

Comment: True. Web application nowadays are usually what you call a single page application. There is no 'page navigation' via browser, but via javascript , using ajax to grab data from the server (or post data). Im sure you can find alot of info about this. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this blog post: [WebSocket - persistent across page loads?](http://tavendo.com/blog/post/websocket-persistent-connections/)

This discusses the issue and options in depth.

Disclosure: I work for Tavendo.

Comment: Very interesting. It is a pity that apparently the websocket multiplexing draft didn't go ahead. It may have been a solution for this scenario.